# Why does UIImageView ignore the image mask?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, calayer

I have a jpg image loaded in a UIImageView, and I try to mask it with an grayscale alpha mask image. It has only a grayscale channel and no RGB or alpha channels.

```
iv = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.jpg"];
self.foreground = iv;

CALayer *mask = [CALayer layer];
UIImage *maskImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mask.jpg"];
mask.contents = (id)[maskImg CGImage];
mask.frame = iv.bounds;

iv.layer.mask = mask;
iv.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

[self addSubview:iv];
```

The images get loaded correctly. But the mask has no effect at all. I tried to invert it in Photoshop and also tried to save it in various other file formats including all types of PNG variation. Nothing gets it to work.

Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try a transparent PNG? With black (alpha = 1) to transparent (alpha = 0) pixels?

Answer (score -1):

Use this code for Image Masking...

```
YourImageview.layer.borderWidth=1.0;
YourImageview.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
YourImageview.layer.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
YourImageview.layer.cornerRadius=30.5;
[YourImageview.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
```